# How to Add to a textview when a button is pressed

Tags: android, crash, textview

I know this has been asked before but I cannot make this work so here is what I have so far

```
class Click extends Activity {
int i=0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Counter);
    mTextView.setText(""+i);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddOne);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Counter);

            i=i+1;
            mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        }
    });
}
```

Every time I run the app in an emulator it crashes

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Click(View) in the activity class com.scouting.corbin.frc_201415_scouting.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'AddOne'
```

I know this is probably something completely stupid but I am new to this and need help thank you in advance.

Comment: show me your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Show `MainActivity` class code

Comment: Probably you have added `android:onClick` for `AddOne` button in xml but forget to create same method in Activity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so all of you helped I completely got rid of that code which was too comlicated for what I was trying to do. After taking bits of suggestions and some reasearch I came up with this

```
public void AddOne(View v) {


        TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Counter);


    i=i+1;
    tv.setText(""+i);
}
```

As you can see much simpler than what I had before and this one works thank you all

Answer (score 1):

As per your logcat.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Click(View)
>   in the activity class
>   com.scouting.corbin.frc_201415_scouting.MainActivity for onClick
>   handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'AddOne'

I suggest you to add `Click(View v)` in your `MainActivity`

```
public void Click(View v)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the root element here. Depending on parent layout include this line in the activity after setContentView().

```
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);// If its some other layout change "RelativeLayout" to your opted layout.
```

and in onClick() method of button, add following.

```
layout.add(tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yopu want To add one Linearlayout in xml file
and set id for your LinearLayout.

```
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
```

And change your addTextView method to following

```
public void addTextView(String text){

LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
TextView textView=new TextView(this);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(textView);
}
```

and call this method from your Forloop

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using the `android:onClick="example_method"` attribute for the button in your xml file. Then create the appropriate method in the class. `public void example_method(View v) {}` Then place the code you have in your onClick function into the new one. It's easier than using an listener.